# Можно ли как то установить прежнюю версию discord.py

Tags: discord.py

Я установил новую версию discord.py и обнаружил что discord_components перестала работать на новой версии.

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете вписать в консоли `pip uninstall discord.py`.
После чего ввести туда `pip install discord.py==НУЖНАЯ_ВЕРСИЯ`

Пример:
`pip install discord.py==1.7.3`